# Parameters passed in the URL

Tags: url-parameters

What are the mechanisms used to hide the parameters being passed in the URL? 
I have noted few websites which uses '#' after their website name, what is the technique used in such websites?

Comment: Do you have an example? Are you talking about single page apps, or passing data through a form post?

Comment: Consider this as an example: https://example.com/Meeting/ViewMeetings?categoryId=1&type=0&RefId=1&meetingType=0 In this website, we can see the category ID; plus if we edit the category ID as 2, certain informations inside the DB are being exposed. How can I hide these confidential parameters from being visible in the url?

Comment: You cannot hide URL parameters. Other websides use other alternatives to post information to the web-server. One technique is using hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Basically, string after hashtag will be handled by browser and won't send over the network.